# php mysql echo variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write an echo to echo a variable and a rtrim function but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Can anyone help with how to write this line correctly?

```
if ($str == ""){echo "$tech_name";}
    else echo "$tech_name" rtrim($str,",");
```

Comment: You can also create a one-liner: `echo (empty($str) ? $tech_name : $tech_name.rtrim($str,',');` or `echo $tech_name.(empty($str) ? '' : rtrim($str,','));`. You don't need the `$tech_name` inside quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the rtrim?

```
else {
    echo "$tech_name" . rtrim($str,",");
}
```

Comment: else{ echo $tech_name . rtrim($str,","); }

Comment: Yes, braces are always a good addition around the conditions -- even the else portion -- I'll update the answer.